# View Twitter avatars in their original size by default

Tags: twitter, profile-picture, avatar

When I click on an avatar of a user on Twitter, it opens as a thumbnail picture. As far as I remember, they were opening as large pictures (in their original size) a week ago or so.

I found a little workaround to display avatars in their original size. At the end of every avatar URL, there is `_bigger.jpg`. I only remove the `_bigger` part and hit enter, and I get the originally sized Twitter avatar. For example,

`http://.../mypicture_bigger.jpg` -> `http://.../mypicture.jpg`

Is there any way to make Twitter do this by default?

Comment: How are you getting this url? I don't now how you get this url, but if i get the ``profile_url```from json of a user I get the full image [Here](http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-development-talk/browse_thread/thread/10ad019ca31fc9a1/e36a62936b6b3109?fwc=1&pli=1) we have a discussion about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been solved per se after I have cleared the history and removed all cookies from Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to make Twitter do this by default without getting an extension to do the job.